# Getting a list of entities in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i am building a video watching application using asp.net core in the backend, and i have created a view table that is a many to many relationship between users and the videos.
example of the table is

```
userId | videoId
-------|--------
-------|--------
-------|--------
```

I am trying to implement a recommended section where the users can see the videos they have not watched.
thats quite easy to implement if all the videos ids are in the view table.
But then i thought what if a video has been created but no one has watched it, the id of that video wouldnt show up in the views table.
so my question is how can i query all the videos in my database where a user hasnt watched the video.
the code i managed to come up with was

```
// user ---> the current user making the api call

var clips = new List<Domain.Clip>();
var notViewed = await _context.Views.Where(x => UserId != user.id).ToListAsync();
     
      foreach (var view in notViewed)
      {
          clips.Add(await _context.Clips.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == view.ClipId && x.Game == game));
      }
```

but this comes with the assumption that all the videos in my database are watched.
can anyone help me with the structure of this query?

Comment: I've replaced your `[asp.net-web-api]` (.NET Framework) tag with the .NET Core version (`[asp.net-core-webapi]`). Feel free to revert the change if it's not correct.

Comment: You have to start with the `Clips` table and exclude those where an entry in `Views` exists with VideoId=ClipId and UserId=current user

Comment: @KlausGütter sorry i dont really understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: How about something like: `var clipIdsTheUserWatched = _context.Views.Where(x => x.UserId = user.id).Select(x => x.videoId); var clipsTheUserDidntWatch = _context.Clips.Where(x => !(clipIdsTheUserWatched.Contains(x.Id)))`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s more of an “architecture” concern, but you could record the “number of times watched” in the Clips table - every time someone watches a video. This can be as easy as adding an integer field to Clip - Clip.WatchCount, for example.

And then becomes very easy to query the videos with 0 watches:

```
_context.Clips.Where(c => c.WatchCount == 0);
```

Comment: smart... but @coraks solution seems to fit my use case better. thanks for the help tho. Much appreciated